# C error " incomplete universal character name \u"

Tags: c

I am having trouble with this error.  Note that im a bit new to c programming and im not that familliar with the casual error.

This is my error:

```
incomplete universal character name \u
```

and this is my code(part of it):

```
while( (ch=getchar())!=EOF )
{
    ++caractere;
    switch(ch)
    {
        case '\n': ++linii;break;
        case '\t': ++cuvinte;break;
        case ' ': uiWord=YES;break;
        case '\u': if(uiWord==YES)
        {
            ++cuvinte;
            uiWord=NO;
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me how can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What character are you trying to capture with `case '\u'`?

Comment: "a" to "z" , "1" to "9", and everyother standard character except " . "

Comment: The `case` statement doesn't do regular expressions. (and even if it did, `\u` wouldn't match that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\u` is used with an id (hexadecimal code) to represent a unicode character, for example`\u20AC` is the code for *€*. It cannot be on its own.

Comment: i understand. thanks. it was unclear for me since ive never used it

Answer (score 3):

'\u' means a unicode character and it is written wrong in your code, the correct format is, for example:

'\u2006'

\u should be followed by 4 digits representing the character.

Comment: Four characters in fact, it's an hexadecimal code.

Comment: i understand. thanks. it was unclear for me since ive never used it

Comment: @Djon Four hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a little on some of the other answers: when you use an escape sequence, it's treated as ONE character. `\n` is one character, despite being two keystrokes to type.

Subsequently, `\u1234` is ONE character to the computer's perspective. `\u` has no meaning: you've given it half a character code.

As to how you fix this, this depends on what you want to do. If you're trying to catch just one particular unicode character, change your switch statement to `case '\u1234':` where 1234 is the hex representation of your character's codepoint.

If, instead, you want to deal with characters not representable in ASCII differently, then you may want something similar to:

```
if(ch < 128)
{
// Check for \n, \t and space here
}
else
{
// Unicode or ANSI codepage
}
```